# First variation on double integral

Tags: integration, calculus-of-variations

Currently I am trying to fully understand the paper of [munk1921](http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/reports/1923/naca-report-121.pdf).

In the derivation of the minimum induced drag theorem it is at one point stated (p.378) that in order to minimize drag the following function should be minimized:

$$
J = \int\limits^{\frac{l}{2}}_{\frac{-l}{2}}\int\limits^{\frac{l}{2}}_{\frac{-l}{2}} \frac{f'(x) \cdot f(\xi)}{\xi - x} dx d\xi 
$$

The first variation of this function is defined as:

$$
\delta J = \int\limits^{\frac{l}{2}}_{\frac{-l}{2}} \left(\delta f(x) dx \int\limits^{\frac{l}{2}}_{\frac{-l}{2}} \frac{f'(\xi)}{\xi - x} d\xi \right) + \int\limits^{\frac{l}{2}}_{\frac{-l}{2}}\left( \delta f'(\xi) d \xi \int\limits^{\frac{l}{2}}_{\frac{-l}{2}} \frac{f(x)}{\xi - x} d\xi \right) 
$$
First of all I do not fully understand their notation since the integral sign is outside of the parentheses but I do not see a matching integration factor d-.

But in my understanding of variational calculus this should look something like:

$$
J(f(\cdot) + \sigma \delta(\cdot)) = \int\limits^{\frac{l}{2}}_{\frac{-l}{2}}\int\limits^{\frac{l}{2}}_{\frac{-l}{2}} \left( \frac{ \left( f'(x) + \sigma \delta'(x) \right) \left( f(\xi) + \sigma \delta(\xi) \right) }{\xi - x} \right) dx d\xi
$$

which leads to the minimization solution
$$
\frac{d J(f(\cdot) + \sigma \delta(\cdot))}{d \sigma} \bigg|_{\sigma = 0} = 
\int\limits^{\frac{l}{2}}_{\frac{-l}{2}}
\int\limits^{\frac{l}{2}}_{\frac{-l}{2}}\frac{f'(x) \delta(\xi)}{\xi - x} dx d\xi 
+
\int\limits^{\frac{l}{2}}_{\frac{-l}{2}}
\int\limits^{\frac{l}{2}}_{\frac{-l}{2}}\frac{f(\xi) \delta'(x)}{\xi - x} dx d\xi = 0
$$

Where $\delta(\cdot)$ is an arbitrary function of either x or $\xi$ and x and $\xi$ are two variables that follow the same paths in space.

Now my question is how they arrived at their First variation of the function J?

Comment: Upon the replacement $\delta f \leftrightarrow \delta$, your formula and the formula you quote are identical (provided of course that all the criteria needed for interchanging the order of integration hold and so on). Some looseness of notation can easily be forgiven, especially in older papers. If you really wish to be pedantic about the notation in the quoted formula, move the $dx$ outside the ( ) in the first term and the first $d\xi$ in the second (the second $d\xi$ in the second term should be a $dx$).